# Not getting the whole records using php toolkit

Tags: php, salesforce

I am using the PHP Toolkit and execute the below query

```
SELECT AssetId,CaseNumber, Chat_Confirmation_Taken__c, ClosedDate,Component__c, Description,Id, IsEscalated,Issue_Description__c,RecordTypeId,Status, Subject, type from Case
```

In this query I am not getting `recordTypeId`,`type`,`Component__c` and `Issue_Description__c`. But if I execute the same using the Real Force Explorer tool it gives me the whole result.

Is there anyone who can help me?